# Number of Solutions to $e^{z}-3z-1=0$ in the Unit Disk

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

I am working through some of the past qualifying exams in complex analysis and I am a bit stuck on the question I posed in the title. My immediately thought is use Rouche's Theorem. For instance, I tried letting $f(z)=e^{z}$ and $g(z)=3z+1$ in hopes of getting $|f(z)|\leq |g(z)|$ on $|z|=1$. But this is false since on $|z|=1$.
$$
|f(z)|\leq\sup_{x\in[-1,1]}e^{x}\leq e\not< 2\leq |3z+1|=|g(z)|.
$$
Clearly, there is at least one solution since $z=0$ works. I am thankful for any ideas as to how to proceed.

Comment: There are no poles so just use the Cauchy argument principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Use $f(z)=\exp(z)-1-3z$, $g(z)=-3z$. then $f(z)-g(z)=\exp(z)-1$, and on $|z|=1$, $|\exp(z)-1|\leq \exp(|z|)-1=e-1<3$ (use that $\exp(z)-1=\sum_{n\geq 1} z^n/n!$).

Answer (score 1):

For $z\ne 0$, let $\gamma$ be the line segment connecting $0$ and $z$. Then,
$$|e^z -1| = \left| \int _\gamma e^u du \right| \le \int _\gamma \sup_{u\in \gamma}|e^u| |du| \le e|z| $$

Comment: @LutzL Thank you for your correction. This should be corrected to $e$. Nevertheless this argument gives a exact proof for the question...

Comment: @LutzL We are finding zeros on **unit disk**, so the condition $|z|\le 1$ is appropriate. Your another comment is right, so I made some change of my formula.

Answer (score 1):

Just use **Cauchy's argument principle** [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle), [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArgumentPrinciple.html):

For a function $f$ meromorphic on a set enclosed by contour $C$:
$$\oint_{C}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz = 2\pi i(N-P)$$

Where $N$ are number of zeros and  $P$ are number of poles of  $f(z)$ inside contour $C$ (on said set).

I could not find right symbol for direction, but should of course be correctly oriented Jordan curve and all that. The unit circle counterclockwise will probably do.

[Wolfram Alpha command](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=approximate%20(%5Cint_0%5E(-2*pi)%20(exp(exp(x*i))%20-3)%2F(exp(exp(x*i))-3*exp(x*i)-1)dx)*2%2F(pi)) for integral.

Answer (score 0):

There is only the one solution.

An elementary proof goes as follows:

Let $z=x+iy$ with $x,y$ real and $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$.  Then 
$$
e^x\cos y = 3x+1\\
e^x\sin y = 3y
$$
The first of these can be solved for $y$, giving (using the fact that  $|y|$ cannot be greater than $1$ to eliminate all the other values of arc cosine)
$$
y = \pm \cos^{-1} (e^{-x}(1+3x))
$$
Using the $-$ sign, the second equation becomes 
$$
e^x \sqrt {1-e^{-2x}(1+3x)^2} = 3 \cos^{-1}(e^{-x}(1+3x))
$$
The argument of the arc cosine is greater than $1$ for all $0<x\leq 1$ so for this equation to hold, $x$ must not be positive. However, for $-1 \leq x\leq 0$, 
 $
e^x \sqrt {1-e^{-2x}(1+3x)^2} $
 is concave upward and its derivative at $x=0$ is less negative than the derivative of $
 3 \cos^{-1}(e^{-x}(1+3x)) $.  Thus for $x\leq 0$ these are only equal at $x=0$.

Using the $+$ sign, of course is even more hopeless for finding another solution, since for $-1\leq x <0$ the LHS is negative and the RHS is positive.

So the only solution is $x=0$.  And then $\sin y = 3y$ forces $y=0$.